# URL formatting: can '&' be included before '?' in the URL?

Tags: url, query-string

https://www.example.com/&audience=testingting?internal-abhishek-jwt=random_string

Is this a valid URL? i.e is it fine to have **&audience** first and **?internal-abhishek-jwt** as the second query paramter?

Please note **audience** has **&** as prefix

Comment: The query string **starts** with `?`.

Comment: So the answer is no

Comment: to clarify the terminology - `&` is not a prefix, it's a separator

Comment: These are equally valid: `https://www.example.com/?internal-abhishek-jwt=random_string&audience=testingting` and `https://www.example.com/?audience=testingting&internal-abhishek-jwt=random_string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a valid URL?

The [URL spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) says that the path should be expressed per these rules:

> ```
>   path          = path-abempty    ; begins with "/" or is empty
>                 / path-absolute   ; begins with "/" but not "//"
>                 / path-noscheme   ; begins with a non-colon segment
>                 / path-rootless   ; begins with a segment
>                 / path-empty      ; zero characters
>
>   path-abempty  = *( "/" segment )
>   path-absolute = "/" [ segment-nz *( "/" segment ) ]
>   path-noscheme = segment-nz-nc *( "/" segment )
>   path-rootless = segment-nz *( "/" segment )
>   path-empty    = 0<pchar>
>   segment       = *pchar
>   segment-nz    = 1*pchar
>   segment-nz-nc = 1*( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / "@" )
>                 ; non-zero-length segment without any colon ":"
>
>   pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
> ```

Which, to cut a long story short, allows the types of character defined on the last line in a segment (which is where you want to put your `&`).

And if we look at [`sub-delims`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.2):

> ```
>  sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
>              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
> ```

… so `&` is allowed.

---

That said, it is **highly unusual** to see a `&` in a URL outside of a query string.

If you put one there then it is not unlikely that someone transcribing the URL will assume you made a mistake and change it … thus breaking it.

So they are best avoided.

---

> i.e is it fine to have &audience first and ?internal-abhishek-jwt as the second query paramter?

No.

The `?` **starts** the query string. Putting them in that order makes `&audience` part of the **path**.

Comment: Unusual but if the file is something like `tips&tricks.html` then maybe. (Although personally I'd rename that to `tips-and-tricks.html` but that's opinion-based). Of course the bigger issue is if the link is in an `<a>` tag and the bit after the `&` happens to look like an escape sequence. The most common blunder I've seen is `something&current`, which becomes `something¤t` and breaks it. This also applies to query-strings, though...