# can '?' separator be included twice in the URL

Tags: javascript, url, query-string

https://www.websitename.com/?audience=testingting?internal-abhishek-jwt=random_string

Is this a valid URL? i.e is it fine to have two '?' separators in the URL?

Note: Due to limitations, I can not add '&' to internal-abhishek-jwt=random_string

Comment: no, it can't, there's only one "?" and for other arguments we write "&" to separate between them

Comment: The 2nd `?` should be an `&`. Multiple `?` can be included, but they should be `url_encoded` (`?audience=testing%3Finternal- ...`)

Comment: "Due to limitations, I can not add '&'…"—well _that's_ your problem. Ask about _that_. This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Answer (score 0):

It isn't. You have to URL encode the second one if you want to use it as a parameter or use '&' symbol instead if you wanna separate your arguments (which seems to be the case here).

Some further explanation [here](https://launchschool.com/books/http/read/what_is_a_url)

Answer (score 0):

The `?` [still](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68591332/19068) indicates the **start** of the query string.

Segments of the query string are separated by `&` characters.

This will be parsed as:

```
key:   audience
value: testingting?internal-abhishek-jwt=random_string
```